# Boss seems to be giving one colleague pay rises?

Tags: salary

As a project manager, I am managing a cross functional team, one developer in my team who is quite talented has already got a pay rise. Boss is currently unhappy with another developer and during the conversation he has suggested getting rid of the developer and increasing the pay of the remaining developer as an act to retain him and keep him motivated.

At that moment, I felt overlooked, I gave him the benefit of the doubt initially but it is playing on my mind since he has already got a pay rise and I haven't? I have never complained once, and was happy for him to get a pay rise ahead of me understanding that we are a tight ship with the view of the building the team being important.

Is this an innocent mistake, should I ask my boss for a pay rise?

Comment: You will virtually never get a pay raise (other than annual cost of living raises if your company still does those) without asking for it.

Comment: That was how my colleague for the pay rise, but this time round he never asked for it, my boss suggested it out of his own accord which left me puzzled. Could it be because he knows my colleague is more money oriented then me? Insecurity coming through?

Comment: @HLGEM if the original payrise wasn't close to what was originally asked for (due to budget restraints) the boss might think it a good idea to now meet what was originally asked for in order to keep the developer happy and retain his services. getting rid of the developer he is unhappy with would free up resource and enable him to do this.

Comment: @bobo2000  *Could it be because he knows my colleague is more money oriented then me? Insecurity coming through?* Those are possibilities but impossible for anyone but your boss to know for sure.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere thanks for your feedback as usual. Resumed job hunting, company is too frugal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the original payrise wasn't close to what was originally asked for (due to budget restraints) the boss might think it a good idea to now meet what was originally asked for in order to keep the developer happy and retain his services. getting rid of the developer he is unhappy with would free up resource and enable him to do this.

However your pay is completely separate issue, you are not due a pay rise simply because someone else got one. If you think you deserve a pay rise and can make the case for one then ask for one and make your case to your boss. If they value what you bring to the table and wish to retain your services and they have the budget for it then you will get one. Otherwise get another job that pays what you think you are worth.

Comment: And further, you now know that financially the time is right for them to give you a raise with money being freed up in the budget.